# ACF Задать для Ссылки значение по умолчанию?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Есть ли какой-то способ назначить значение для [ссылки элемента плагина acf](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/link/) значение по умолчанию, что б оно отображалось в админке ?

```
<?php if ($link = get_field('link')): ?>
  <a class="btn" href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" <?php if($link['target']){ echo 'target="_blank"';} ?>><?php echo $link['title']; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Можно ли сделать, что б при создании нового поста у него в $link['title'] уже было прописано дефолтное значение и оно отображалось в админке поста ?
[image: acf link]

*Я понимаю, что я в `php` могу добавить проверку на пустоту значения поля, и выводить его там, но это не будет отображаться в админке.

Comment: Можете установить дефолтное значение посредством фильтра, например [acf/load_field/name=your_field_name](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/), только перед добавлением значений, проверьте что поле пустое. Если я Вас верно понял, конечно же.

Comment: А можно подробнее, как оно должно работать ? Я что-то не могу разобраться, в переменной `var_dump($link);` у меня 3 значения ссылки ["title"] ["url"] ["target"] Как мне задать по умолчанию ["title"] ? Но что б её можно было пересохранить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте фильтр [acf/load_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/)

```
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=your_field_name', function ($field) {
    // Проверка что поле изначально пустое
    if (empty($field['value'])) {
        $field['value'] = [
            'title' => esc_html__('Default Title', 'textdomain'),
            'url' => 'https://example.com', // можете установить ссылку по-умолчанию при необходимости
            'target' => '_blank' // можете установить атрибут target при необходимости
        ];
    }

    return $field;
});
```

Comment: Что-то не работает. Сейчас в вашем примере описка... там где `array(`... Скобка не закрыта.   А где брать этот `key=field_` который указан в документации ? Попробовал `add_filter('acf/load_field/name=therapist_link',` не срабатывает, а ключей этих что-то не наблюдаю в том месте где создаю новый элемент ACF

Comment: @BlackStar1991 скобочку потерял, спасибо. Должно работать посредством `name=therapist_link` если таково имя поля, у меня локально с `name=your_field_name` работает (уверены что поле пустое у той записи на которой Вы это проверяете?). Отображение `key` можете настроить в `Screen Options` в правом верхнем углу.

Comment: Оказываеться оно работает, но не совсем. Что б запись произошла в базу данных надо клацнуть в записи на задание параметров той ссылке. (произвести активацию). Тогда дефолтное значение появляеться. А пока на Link не нажать дефолт не появиться. Спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 я думал что оно Вам нужно скорее как плейсхолдер.

Comment: Заказчику. Что-то по типу кнопки/ссылки "Купи сейчас"  но если ему взбредет в голову обозвать данную кнопку другим синонимом, что б мог это сделать... Хотя скорее всего там всегда будет дефолтное значение.